# Repeatedly using one subprocess.Popen instance in python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen, sudo

I am working on scripting a process in Python, and in my code I make several command line calls using `p = subprocess.Popen(['example', 'command', 'and', 'args')`. I recently ran into an issue that several of the command line calls need `sudo` permissions, and as such the user ends up having to type their sudo password several times, which is not desired.
Is there a way to only spawn one shell instance, and repeatedly use it throughout the program?  Can this be done even if the different commands are run from different classes? 
Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to do this using the paramiko library.

Comment: Thanks for the suggests. Is there a way to do this without using any external libraries? I was hoping there would be a Popen configuration that allows me to do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For concreteness, suppose your program looked like this:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('fdisk -l'))
proc.communicate()
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('fdisk -l'))
proc.communicate()
```

Running it as a normal user returns no output.

But if you run

```
% sudo python /path/to/test.py
```

then you are prompted once for the root password, and both `subprocess.Popen` commands run as root.